# Vlookup in VBA and adding text

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I have two different sheets in my work book. Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. I need to do vlookup between these two sheets (A column in both sheets) and if sheet 1 contains any element from Sheet 2, the the text "UG" should be updated in sheet 1 in "AE4" cell.

Is it possible in VBA?

Comment: Yes it is, just use Google a little bit (it's not that hard), and I promise you you'll find a lot of results, and a few good ones here at home on SO

Comment: thanks will try google first and post here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below and modify to fit you:

```
Cells(specify, specify).Formula = "=VLookup(RC20,Sheet1!R2C2:R273C22,17,FALSE)"
```

Change the relevant parameters in the VLOOKUP to suit you.

Use this to then figure out how to add an If statement